# How to handle Zend Framework End User INI/Config settings

Tags: zend-framework, config, ini

I have searched and searched for this but I think my terminology isn't correct as it keeps giving me the application settings for the zend site rather than an application settings for the End User.

I'd like to have a config.ini type file that the end user can edit values in.  I'd like it to be ONLY the settings I wish them to see and to be able to create the value names as I think would make sense to them.  So it would be something like

```
[General]
SiteName=MySite
ShowResources=TRUE

[Database]
Server=myServer
databasepath=mydbpath
...
```

So my two questions.
1. What is this type of file called because when I search application settinsg, I get the ZF application settings not one for an end user (presumably)

1. What is the best way to handle this type of file?

Thanks

Comment: Be specific about what you mean by "end user".  I can't tell if you're talking about some random person with a web browser, or someone who is trying to install and run the software you're writing.  If it's the former, they shouldn't be editing .ini files.  If it's the latter, they *still* probably shouldn't be editing .ini files, but if they are, just create a default file, have them edit it, and use Zend_Config to get the values into your app.

Comment: The End User to  me, or the person who is buying my product to use on their own web site. Not a site visitor or person browsing via the net.

Comment: So they're using a checkout of your ZF app, and with it, they'll only ever be connecting to one (i.e., their own local) database?

Comment: Presumably thats correct.  I hesitate to have them edit any true application settings files and would prefer they edit some other harmless INI type file for setup information. eg. database, user credentials, etc.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bootstrap add:

```
protected function _initConfig()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/config.ini');

    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);

    return $config;
}
```

replace config.ini with whatever you want the filename to be.

You can then access this config object anywhere in your application either as an application resource or through the registry (`Zend_Registry::get('config')`). So to get the SiteName from your example:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
echo $config->General->SiteName;
```

For things like database settings, you'll want to access these in the bootstrap so you can use them to setup other resources. I would recommend you don't try and include database settings in your application.ini as well, instead manually setup the DB resource by adding another bootstrap method:

```
protected function _initDb()
{
    $this->bootstrap('config');
    $config = $this->getResource('config');

    $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
        'host'     => $config->Database->Server,
        'username' => $config->Database->Username,
        'password' => $config->Database->Password,
        'dbname'   => $config->Database->Dbname
    ));

    return $db;
}
```

To explain this some more, `$this->bootstrap('config');` ensures the config resource is loaded first. `$this->getResource('config');` returns the config resource (the one created by the _initConfig() method). It then uses the data from this object to create the DB connection.

Comment: Thanks very much Tim.  This helped lay it out for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's an INI file, which you can read and write via Zend_Config.
2. ZF has no concept of "user settings" -- users are defined by you, not by the framework.

Apps usually store user configs in a database, but that's totally up to you. You could store a directory of INI files instead. Either way, you have to do the implementation yourself.

Edit: Given that you have a ZF app that you're distributing to the customer, and they're only ever going to connect to one database with it, that changes things significantly. (I thought you originally meant that you'd have one instance of the app simultaneously connecting to multiple databases.)

In your case, I would use the standard ZF application/configs/application.ini file for your application's "internal" settings. Then, I'd have a separate local.ini (or whatever) in that same application/configs directory, which contains only those settings that you want the customer editing. Distribute a skeleton local.ini file with the app, that has instructions right in it, something like this:

```
; Remove the comment from this line.
;configured = 1

; You need to put your database credentials in here.
db_host = "PUT YOUR DATABASE SERVER NAME HERE"
db_user = "PUT YOUR DATABASE USERNAME HERE"
db_pass = "PUT YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD HERE"
```

Then just load the local.ini file via Zend_Config. I'd also add a check to your index controller's init method that checks to see if you're properly configured:

```
$localConfig = Zend_Registry::get('local_config'); // or wherever you put it
if (!$localConfig->configured) {
    $this->_helper->redirector('config', 'error');
}
```

And then make a error/config view that says:

```
You didn't read the instructions. Go do that now.
```

Note there's nothing stopping the customer from editing anything they want, but this makes a logical separation and makes it harder to accidentally screw something up.

Comment: 1. Yes but what type of INI file would i search for "end user ini file" doesnt seem to be giving the results I'm looking for.  What is this type of end user INI file typically referred to as?

2. I understand this might not be inherent to ZF but I'm curious as to the best way to handled this type of implementation.

Comment: There are no "types of INI files" -- there are just INI files. You're not finding anything relating to using INI files for per-user settings because nobody does it that way.

Comment: check documentation, possible examples are useful for you: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html

Comment: Okay, so would you refer to this as "per-user" files? And if no one is doing it that way, in what way are they doing it? I don't believe I can put database connection information in the database.  Where are people having them store this, that is preferrably not within the actual projects application settings? Or are they having users edit those files directly?